# Wix installer - cannot uninstall perUser package

Tags: wix, windows-installer

After installation of perUser msi package I cannot uninstall it.

[image: Error while uninstalling]

When selecting (`Browse`) package - that I installed - there is an error: 'selected package is not valid package for this product'.
Here's my code:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?><Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'>
   <Product Id='a871a539-5954-44b7-810d-caed5d09e4c5' Name='x' Language='1033'
            Version='1.1.0.0' Manufacturer='M' UpgradeCode='a871a539-5954-44b7-810d-caed5d09e4c5'>
      <Package Description='x'
                Comments='x'
                Manufacturer='x' InstallerVersion='200' Compressed='yes' InstallScope='perUser' />

  <Media Id='1' Cabinet='product.cab' EmbedCab='yes' />

  <Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
            <Directory Id='AppDataFolder' Name='AppData'>
                 <Directory Id='xFolder' Name='x' />
            </Directory>
        </Directory>


           <Component Id='xComponent' Guid='a871a539-5954-44b7-810d-caed5d09e4c5'
                Directory='xFolder'>
            <RemoveFolder Id="Removex" On="uninstall" />
            <!-- registry entry to be used as keypath -->
            <RegistryValue Root="HKCU"
                Key="Software\M\x"
                Name="component.xcomponent.installed"
                Type="integer"
                Value="1"
                KeyPath="yes"/>

              <File Id='myFile' Name='myFile.txt' DiskId='1' Source='myFile.txt' />
... files here
</Component>
<Feature Id='xFeature' Title='x feature' Level='1'>
     <ComponentRef Id='xComponent' />
  </Feature>
```

Installation process is ok - no errors. Files are in correct place. Registry key is added.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [the installed product does not match the installation source(s) error when uninstalling a windows service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648521/the-installed-product-does-not-match-the-installation-sources-error-when-unins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - as Wim Coenen said - that question helped me resolve problem.

However instead of executing steps in that question I cleaned registry.
The problem was that I installed this package many times changing GUID and other parameters, so there was quite a mess in registry. I searched registry by Manufacturer and Name.

After cleaning up everything was ok.