# Network resource that is unavailable or enter an alternate path

Tags: windows, windows-installer

When i try to start one application (for instance application A.exe) error was throwing from already installed msi file (for Ex: B.msi) as "The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable or enter an alternate path to a folder containing the installation package 'B.msi'"
I have read some articles related to this error but all of them explaining if installer have any issues (if file have been damaged, deleted, moved, or quarantined by an anti-virus application) this error will occur but here when I try to launch one application then it is showing above mentioned error with another package name (B.msi) which I already installed.
Please let me know the cause of this issue it would be helpful to trace out this issue.
Note: For older version of our application don't have this issue (For creating installer earlier we have used Wise tool now using WIX tool. Is there any issue with WIX installer?).

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51287875/why-installer-runs-after-click-on-shortcut/51294985#51294985 when it can't find the original MSI to repair from.

Answer (score 2):

***Self-Repair Problems***: This is generally a self-repair issue. I have written more times about this than I care to count, I'll see if I can send you here: [**`MSI self-repair - the scourge of society`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50147972/windows-installer-3-1-need-to-install-for-every-user/50160794#50160794).

***Explanation***: What is actually happening is that your installation goes through an integrity check when launced via [an advertised shortcut](https://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/about-windows-installer-shortcuts), and a resource is found to be missing. The MSI will then try to repair itself (self-repair), but it is unable to find the required source files to retrieve the file it needs to reinstall - since the source files are no longer available at the location where you installed from. It is a good idea to install from a permanently available network location using [administrative installations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564619/what-is-the-purpose-of-administrative-installation-initiated-using-msiexec-a/5751980#5751980) - especially for corporations.

***Missing Source Files Resolution***: In your case - to sort out the missing source files - you can either uninstall and reinstall (uninstall should not need source access in normal cases), and then preserve the installation files at a permanently available location (solving the problem for the future), or you can browse to the installation source when you are prompted to do so for your current installation (and there are some ways to automate setting new source paths). The installation source must be the one used to install the software originally (unless you know how to hack it, which is very involved).

***Self-Repair Resolution***: To sort out the actual self-repair conflict, you essentially need to find the culprit component causing the repair in the event viewer and then find some way to resolve the situation. All linked or explained in the above answer ([repeated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50147972/windows-installer-3-1-need-to-install-for-every-user/50160794#50160794)). Proposed "**real-world solutions**" can be found in **section 5** here: **[What do I do when launching an application triggers repeating, endless Windows Installer self-repair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45716108/what-do-i-do-when-launching-an-application-triggers-repeating-endless-windows-i/45716110#45716110)** As a workaround, you might want to try to launch the EXE files in question directly, to verify that the self-repair does not happen (generally this will prevent the self-repair, but it can still happen if there is a COM conflict or some other advanced conflict).

You can see a list of "***Primary Cause of Self-Repair***" some way down in this answer: **[How can I determine what causes repeated Windows Installer self-repair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501028/how-can-i-determine-what-causes-repeated-windows-installer-self-repair/6066263#6066263)** (bad MSI packages with conflicting resources - COM conflicts?, security software quarantining files unexpectedly, cleanup scripts wrecking havoc, etc...). I would recommend you skim this list for ideas.

---

***Uninstall Problems***: This "installation source not found" problem can also occur so it prevents uninstall in special cases. Here is an answer which tries to summarize aspects of this problem: [Powershell Silent Uninstall "Microsoft Report Viewer Runtime 2012"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50475550/powershell-silent-uninstall-microsoft-report-viewer-runtime-2012/50478416#50478416) (somewhat too elaborate, but worth skimming I think).

---

***Some Links*** (for reference and easy retrieval):

- [Installshield 2013 Installscript MSI: Wrong .msi location during Repair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51078998/installshield-2013-installscript-msi-wrong-msi-location-during-repair)
- [Wix / MSI : Unable to uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508179/wix-msi-unable-to-uninstall)
- [Uninstall without an MSI file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334490/uninstall-without-an-msi-file)